# Unable to see Coverage details on Sonarqube Dashboard for C#

Tags: c#, sonarqube, dotcover

Our Sonar Build Environment details as follows:-

```
• SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.6 (64-Bit). 
• Sonar-scanner- Version - 3.0.3.778.
• SonarQube Server Operating System – Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (64-Bit). 
• sonar-csharp-plugin-5.11.0.1761.jar
• Sonar Build Machine Operating System: Windows-7 (64-bit)
```

**Problem Description:-**

I have installed the (sonar-csharp-plugin-5.11.0.1761.jar) successfully, I am able to scan the code as well, However when I tried to configure the dotCover - Coverage report with the below property. I am unable to see the same in our SonarQube dashboard.

```
sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=build\\CoverageReport.html
```

Also I have observed that in Server under Administration-->General Settings-->C# tab I can only File suffixes and Ignore Header comments items. I can't see Coverage details like other language plugins.

So kindly help me to configure the same.

Comment: Hi Mohan,
Just a quick question, are you sure that the path is correct? What I mean is from the top level, is the path to your report only ".\build\coveragereport.html"?

Comment: Hi Amaury, Yes it is correctly set.

Comment: Is there any warning or weird looking message in the log of the analysis?

Comment: Hi Amaury, Even no warning message.

Comment: Do i need to use MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe to scan? Or simply above mentioned standard scanner and version is sufficient?